# Is there an idiom for people who boast too much?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, colloquialisms, idiom-requests

I am looking for **idioms** or informal/slang/colloquial expression for some people that make you think that they are able of building a skyscraper, constructing a spaceship, playing the piano better than Mozart or something very fancy that requires remarkable skills, but when it comes to practice they prove to be completely inadequate.

Comment: As I understand it you are looking for an idiom to describe a person who boasts excessively, not an idiom to describe the act?  I am inclined to downvote all those answers that describe the act because they are not answering the actual question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are tons of them. There's a whole sub-genre based roughly off the phrase "all talk (and no substance)". These generally have the form "all *X*, no *Y*".

Others culled from synonyms on the wictionary link below include:

- All bark and no bite.
- All booster, no payload.
- All bubbles, no bath.
- All crown, no filling.
- All foam, no beer.
- All ham, no let. (For you fans of The Bard)
- All hammer, no nail.
- All icing, no cake.
- All lime and salt, no tequila.
- All mouth and no trousers. (A corruption of [All mouth and trousers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_mouth_and_trousers))
- All shot, no powder.
- All show, no go.
- All sizzle and no steak.
- All talk, no walk.
- All wax and no wick. (Alternatively *All wick and no wax*)

My personal favorite from cattle country here in the USA is to say that a person is [all hat and no cattle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle).

As a note to outsiders, for some people wearing a cowboy hat has become something of a cultural statement. Thus many people wear them who, if confronted with an actual cow, would have no clue which end the "moo" comes out.

Comment: Rephrased this (and made community wiki) in a desperate attempt to stave off the profusion of similar answers. If you have a favorite "All X no Y" saying, I think it would be easier to come by if you post it on the list above or as a comment here, rather than make another similar answer.

Answer (score 10):

I believe a good idiom that describes this situation is [blowing your own trumpet](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/68800.html).

Comment: P.S. I believe an idiom that gets close to describing situation 3 is [when it rains, it pours](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080203205436AA6VJPR).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure "blowing your own trumpet" means that you can't necessarily do what you say you can, though.

Comment: @simchona - You may have a point but, it's the closest that I could think of.

Comment: I like it as an idiom, don't get me wrong.

Comment: @simchona - no offense taken.

Comment: A variant of this is `tooting your own horn`.

Comment: Perhaps related: `blowhard`

Answer (score 6):

> All gong and no dinner.

> All fur coat and no knickers.

Comment: Welcome to *English Language & Usage*, Barrie. I would invite you to edit your answer in order to flesh it out, to give it a bit more context. That would then give other users an incentive to vote, and an high-voted answer is more likely to attract the attention of the poster.

Comment: Actually, both these logically go with my answer, probably as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

**[braggart](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/braggart)** would be an appropriate and pretty generic term for such a person. This word would be appropriate in a formal or informal context. (Note that the verb "to brag" is pretty much synonymous with "to boast", so this is a pretty direct noun formation.)

From the examples you give, I would probably use the adjectives *[delusional](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delusional)* and *[arrogant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrogant)* (*narcissistic* if you want to sound pompous, or *cocky* in slang) to describe such a person. For the former, an appropriate idiom might be:

*He/she is on crack.*

or even,

*What is he/she smoking?*

both alluding to the use of mind-altering drugs (though not usually literally).

Answer (score 5):

> When someone is said to be “***full of hot air***”, it means that he or she talks rather a lot about topics he or she doesn't really understand.

[*[source](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-does-it-mean-to-be-full-of-hot-air.htm)*]

Comment: Or slightly more vulgarly, just "full of (bull)shit".

Answer (score 3):

Because the person *can't* actually do what they say they can, you could say that they cannot [put their money where their mouth is](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/put+your+money+where+your+mouth+is.html):

> If someone puts their money where their mouth is, they back up their words with action.

Comment: This idiom has the meaning "Better do sth instead of talking about it" while I more needed an idiom to emphasize that sb is **boasting** about things they can't do. But it's a good one too.

Answer (score 3):

What about "to have a big head"?

Comment: This is very apt; but it’s more common, I think, as the adjective *big-headed*.

Answer (score 3):

I know you’re looking for a colloquial idiom, but there does actually exist a (rare) word that means this very thing: [***jactator***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100589). It’s a direct borrowing from the identical Latin word.  The OED marks it as *“obsolete rare*<sup>-0</sup>”, with the last citation given from back in the 18<sup>th</sup> century.

Somewhat more current and less rare is the related term [***jactation***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100588), whose sense 2 is “Boasting, bragging, ostentatious display.” It is not marked as obsolete or rare, or even archaic.  Here are that sense’s citations:

> - 1576      J. Woolton *Christian Man*. sig. H.iiii<sup>v</sup>,      If wee vse them with excesse, fylthy pleasure, vaine iactation:‥we abuse Gods good gyftes.
> - 1604      T. Wright *Passions of Minde* (new ed.) i. vi. 26,      I could adde‥Envy, Emulation‥Iactation or Boasting.
> - 1825      *London Mag.* I. 379      There is no surer sign of vulgarity than jactation of gentility.
> - 1886      Saintsbury in *Macmillan's Mag.* July 171      The tedious burlesque, the more tedious jactation which disfigure his work.

Its pronuncation is  /dʒækˈteɪʃən/ , and its entymology is:

> Latin *jactātiōn-em*, n. of action from *jactāre* to throw, toss about, discuss, boast of, refl. to talk boastfully, make an ostentatious display, frequentative of *jacĕre* to throw; compare French *jactation* (Cotgrave).

I suspect that *jactator* has strong potential for all sorts of intentional misunderstandings in various wicked puns. :)

Probably only students of Latin or speakers of derived Romance tongues would understand its original meaning. For example, *jactarse de algo* is “to boast of something” in Spanish, and is a perfectly common use, not a rare one.

[Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jactator%2C+jactation&year_start=1600&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows scant but measurable use of *jactator* compared with somewhat more frequent use of *jactation*, which actually seems to be on the rise since 2000. It might be used in its pathology sense, though.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Adams suggests "[Topper](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Topper)".

Answer (score 2):

*Ten cent millionaire* was my father's favorite expression for people who try to glorify themselves.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's a good idea to add further detail and reliable references to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some people can't [walk the talk.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_the_talk)

Comment: Or you might say the person, "Talks a big game."

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorites: *[Blowhard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blowhard)*

Answer (score 1):

*Braggart*, *blowhard*, and the more vulgar *bullshitter* all work well in daily, idiomatic American English.

Answer (score 1):

---

> ***"A legend in his own mind"***  seems fitting...

---

Answer (score 0):

> [grandiose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grandiose)
>   1 : characterized by affectation of grandeur or splendor or by absurd exaggeration *Example*: They did not believe his grandiose claims.

That fellow is **grandiose**; he told everyone he discovered the Fountain of Youth, but it was only a beer keg. I said, "You're joking!", but he was serious.