# Synonym for "bullshit" in a status meeting

Tags: synonyms

The context is a daily stand up meeting on a software project where developers tell the managers their status.  It is very easy for developers to bullshit, where they sound like they are busy, accomplishing something, doing something technical, or otherwise misdirecting.  These are empty words and can easily be called out.  What is a good business-ese word for this kind of bullshit?

Comment: It's never good "business-ese" to heap scorn on the contributions of others in a business status meeting. But if all you're bothered about is avoiding "lowering the tone" even more with gratuitous scatology, take your pick from synonyms of [*waffle, twaddle, blather, etc.*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/waffle)

Comment: Any synonym, however weakened from BS, will still be confrontational. You may have to redirect, before the meeting tell people to emphasize content and not feel obligated to fill time with words (give them the opportunity to 'pass'. Also you may get better advice over at http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: E.g. Saying "That's empty blather" while not a taboo word, is still confrontational.

Comment: This sounds like you're using **Scrum** as a project management style.  If so, are you the scrummaster?  If so, then it's your duty to call them out, I believe.  Perhaps something like "That doesn't really sound like you're making the progress you need to be.  What are your roadblocks?"  If you're not the scrummaster and that person isn't technical, you might consider meeting with them informally to voice your concerns or, as a more scrum-like option, meet with the BSers and ask them how you can help.  Also estimating story points is a great time to say how much effort an item should take.

Comment: Maybe you could borrow “sound and fury” from Shakespeare (I’d omit the notion of “signifying nothing”; those who get the reference will know it’s there and hopefully stop BSing altogether without being overly pissed, while those who don’t get it will probably just lower the decibels of their BS, but that’s a start): … “From now on could we/you please try to dispense with some of the [insignificant] sound and fury that has surfaced at/dominated our previous meetings?”

Comment: Thank for all the replies.  I am trying to do a review and trying to convey that someone speaks in a way that is not direct or of little substance, but conveys the appearance of it.  I think "sound and fury" has the right idea in that it is euphemistic but not the dull passive business speak phrasing I am looking for.

Comment: related: [what-is-deliberately-using-complex-sentences-to-confuse-people-called](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254643/what-is-deliberately-using-complex-sentences-to-confuse-people-called)

Comment: *Looking busy, telling a good story.*

Comment: This question seems related but not identical to the other question, which was closed anyway.

Comment: There are several idioms in the spirit of “sound and fury,” for example, [“all sizzle and no steak”](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+sizzle+and+no+steak) (alternatively, “all sizzle and no bacon”),  [“all hat and no cattle”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle#English),  [“all talk and no action”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_talk_and_no_action#English),  and  [“talking the talk but not walking the walk”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/talk-the-talk-walk-the-walk). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  [“Talking through one’s hat”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/talk-through-your-hat) is similar. See also [Is there an idiom for people who boast too much?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41496/26083).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. This could easily surpass the putative dup. in attention and answer quality.

Answer (score 1):

### Obfuscate

You might say they are **obfuscating**, or it is to **obfuscate**. This might sound a bit like college-level word usage, but it's actually a cheeky word you're likely to hear in an office situation.

OED bears me out:

Verb. trans. To cast into darkness or shadow; to cloud, obscure.

### Examples:

1. *They were trying to **obfuscate** their lack of progress with technical jargon.*
2. *Developers have mastered the arts of computer science and **obfuscation**.*

Comment: +1 since obfuscation is also a term used in development where code is deliberately made hard to read, usually via an automatic tool, in case it is decompiled.

Answer (score 0):

You might try "**Sales Puff**"

Even if your workmates don't know the word it's meaning is pretty self evident and easy to remember.

"*John, let's quit the sales puff and let us know either what your real estimate for completion is or let us know where you're getting hung up*"

It is even a recognized legal term:

> **[Puffing](https://definitions.uslegal.com/p/puffing/)** Law and Legal Definition uslegal.com
>
> The term “puffing” refers to “extravagant claims made by sellers in order to attract buyers.”
>
> It is the exaggeration of the good points of a product, a business, real property, and the prospects for future rise in value, profits and growth.
>
> However, it cannot be the basis of a lawsuit for fraud or breach of contract, unless the exaggeration exceeds the reality.
>
> If the puffery includes outright lies or has no basis in fact, a legal action for rescission of the contract or for fraud against the seller is possible. Puffing cannot be legally construed to be a guarantee.

---

another use of "puff" in this way:

**puff piece**  is more related to journalism of exaggerated praise -- I think less useful in the situation you describe

[Wikipedia has it's own article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffery) on "**puffery**"